# python3 how to define ctypes struct for return type from imported library

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, fann

I'm trying to use ctypes to use [fann](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/) (a neural network library written in C) in python3. Here is my abridged code so far:

```
from ctypes import *
cdll.LoadLibrary("/usr/local/lib/libdoublefann.dylib")
fann = CDLL("/usr/local/lib/libdoublefann.dylib")


# Call fann to create a neural network
nn = fann.fann_create_from_file(b'/Users/xxxxx/Code/fanncode/net/nnf_25_1339802027.net')

# this outputs 3909360
print(nn)
```

If I try and call any other functions in the fann library against the nn variable, which should now be a fann neural network, I either get `Segmentation fault: 11` or `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'getMSE'` (for example). I think my problem is that according to the ctypes documentation, the variable nn is ending up being an int, whereas the fann documentation for the function fann_create_from_file states:

```
FANN_EXTERNAL struct fann *FANN_API fann_create_from_file(const char * configuration_file)
```

So I think I need to declare:

```
class FANN_API(Structure):
    <fields and things which I don't know what they should be>
```

And then do:

```
fann.fann_create_from_file.restype = FANN_API
```

My problem is that I can't find what the struct FANN_API should be. Line 130 of fann.h states `#define FANN_API` but thats it, no definition or anything follows it.

Am I correct in my guess about needing to define the struct? If so, then how can I find out the format of it to declare in the python code? If not then can anybody suggest what I might need to do/what to read to get my code to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `ctypes` the arguments and return codes of functions.  You should be able to get away with `c_void_p` (void*) as the type unless you have some reason to manipulate the contents of the structure:

```
fann.fann_create_from_file.restype = c_void_p
fann.fann_create_from_file.argtypes = [c_char_p]
```

Note that `struct fann *` is the return type of your function.  `FANN_API` represents the calling convention.  You've said it is defined as `#define FANN_API`.  Being defined as nothing means the default calling convention, so your use of `CDLL` should be correct.

If you need to define something more specific, post the definition of `struct fann`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up a bit for me, I tried using c_void_p but that doesn't work. I need to delve into the FANN source code and figure out how to make  `struct fann` in ctypes.